# How do I convert a specific column in my R dataframe from long to wide and display the counts and percentages?

Tags: r, count, grouping

My dataframe df is 
`District   State   Mode`
 `A          State1  Cycle`
 `D          State2  Car`
`A          State1  Cart`
 `C          State1  Walk`
`B          State1  Car`
 I want to count the modes of transport in each district.

I want the output like this:
 `District State Cycle Car Cart Walk`
 `A        State1 1    0   1    0`
`B        State1 0    1   0    0`
`C        State1 0    0   0    1`
`D        State2 0    1   0    0`  
 I tried using aggregate and table.

```
grouped_data <- aggregate(df, by=list(df$district, df$Mode,df$State), FUN=length) 
grouped_data<-as.data.frame(table(df))
```

But it is not giving me the desired output.I also would like the percentages for each mode to be displayed as separate columns.

Comment: `df %>%
  count(District, Mode) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Mode, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))`

Comment: This works. Thank you. How do I get the percentages as well in separate columns just like the counts? Also, I would like to retain the state column.

Comment: `df %>% count(District, State, Mode) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Mode, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))`